# Delete old Urls from database

Tags: products, url-rewrite, sitemaps

Good morning!

Is it possible to delete old url records in the database without harm the system?

My problem is a shop that first started with one storeview in english.

Years later they added a new language. So far no problem.

The problem now is the sitemap. The generator seems to find some old urls to the ids that were originally for the english storeview. And so we got a XML-Sitemap that has for some products the old url.

I tried so far to truncate the core_url_rewrite but that had no effect.
And I really don't want to debug the whole sitemap generator script to fix this problem because I guess that this is problem inside their database with their old urls.